# Zlib decompress bytes with unknown compressed length in C

Tags: c, compression, zlib

I am trying to write my own png reader without any external libraries. I need to use Zlib to decompress the png's IDAT chunk. I have managed to do it in python using `zlib.decompress()`, and I am trying to replicate it in C. I was reading over zlib's docs and found `uncompress()`, however it requires a destination length which I would not know.

I could set a destination to be much larger than possible for the png, but this seems like a cop-out and would break my program If I had a really big picture. However, i have found a function `inflate()` which can be used multiple times. If I could do this, i could `realloc()` memory if needed with each call. Yet I don't understand the docs for it very well and have not found much examples for this type of thing. Could anyone provide some code or help point me in the right direction?

Comment: As you guessed, the `zlib` functions are _stream_ oriented. So, you use a loop and `realloc` to expand the length of the decompressed data buffer, a chunk at a time (e.g.) Before each decompress [deflate] call, you call `realloc` with an increasing length,. You set the size in the `z_stream` struct and the function will stop when the buffer is full [or no more input data is left]. You loop until all the data has been decompressed. The `zlib.h` file has fairly complete documentation. For an example, download the source to a program that uses `zlib` (e.g. `gzip`) and `zlib` source has examples

Comment: Note that using `realloc` will require the entire existing buffer to be copied every time, so it should not be called too often (I would say not more than once ever 4096 bytes). If you want better performance, you should increase this amount, or better: Not use `realloc` at all, but handle several buffers. However, I wouldn't worry about this for now. You can always optimize later, once it is working.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel It would be extremely inefficient to have a constant `realloc()` frequency, e.g. "once every 4096 bytes". Then every byte will be copied many times. If instead you _double_ the memory size at each `realloc()`, then you can show that the bytes will be copied only once on average.

Comment: @MarkAdler: Yes, I agree that an adaptive buffer size would be better than a constant one, especially when the file size can be large. I also agree that your proposed algorithm of doubling the buffer size for every allocation would probably be best, as that algorithm does not copy memory more than once on average.

Comment: @MarkAdler: As far as I can tell, the most efficient solution would be not to call `realloc` at all, but to instead have an array or linked list of pointers to fixed-length memory buffers. That way, new buffers could be allocated as required, and no memory would have to be copied. However, if the programmer's task requires these buffers to be merged afterwards, in order to work with them, then all memory buffers will have to be copied once. In that case, my solution would have no advantage over the `realloc` solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *do* know the destination length. Exactly. The PNG header information tells you how many rows, how many columns, and how many bytes per pixel. Multiply it all out, add a byte per row for the filtering, and you have your answer.

Allocate that amount of memory, and decompress into that.

Note that there can be multiple IDAT chunks, but combined they contain a single zlib stream.

Comment: Well, that's some useful information, I didn't know you could get the length like that. And also arent you the creator of the Zlib library? You're one of my heroes dude. =)